# How to increase spacing between two rows in a large matrix?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, matrices

Currently, here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath,amsthm,enumitem,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,multicol,tikz,pgfplots,tkz- 
euclide,relsize,framed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{fontscale/.style = {font=\relsize{#1}}}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.750in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumii}.}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}


\begin{document}



\[G_{10} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-\frac{2}{25} & -\frac{17}{100} & -\frac{13}{50} & -\frac{7}{20} & - 
\frac{11}{25} & -\frac{53}{100} & -\frac{31}{50} & -\frac{71}{100} & - 
\frac{4}{5} \\ 
\frac{2}{25} & 0 & -\frac{1}{25} & -\frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{5} & - 
\frac{7}{25} & -\frac{9}{25} & -\frac{11}{25} & -\frac{13}{25} & - 
\frac{3}{5} \\
\frac{17}{100} & \frac{1}{25} & 0 & \frac{1}{50} & -\frac{1}{20} & - 
\frac{3}{25} & -\frac{19}{100} & -\frac{13}{50} & -\frac{33}{100} & - 
\frac{2}{5} \\
\frac{13}{50} & \frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{50} & 0 & \frac{1}{10} & 
\frac{1}{25} & -\frac{1}{50} & -\frac{2}{25} & -\frac{7}{50} & - 
\frac{1}{5} \\
\frac{7}{20} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{20} & -\frac{1}{10} & 0 & 
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{20} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{20}  & 0 \\
\frac{11}{25} & \frac{7}{25} & \frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{25} & -\frac{1} 
{5} & 0 & \frac{8}{25} & \frac{7}{25} & \frac{6}{25} & \frac{1}{5} \\
\frac{53}{100} & \frac{9}{25} & \frac{19}{100} & \frac{1}{50} & - 
\frac{3}{20} & -\frac{8}{25} & 0 & \frac{23}{50} & \frac{43}{100} & 
\frac{2}{5} \\
\frac{31}{50} & \frac{11}{25} & \frac{13}{50} & \frac{2}{25} & - 
\frac{1}{10} & -\frac{7}{25} & -\frac{23}{50} & 0 & \frac{31}{50} & 
\frac{3}{5} \\
\frac{71}{100} & \frac{13}{25} & \frac{33}{100} & \frac{7}{50} & - 
\frac{1}{20} & -\frac{6}{25} & -\frac{43}{100} & -\frac{31}{50} & 0 & 
\frac{4}{5} \\
\frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & -\frac{1} 
{5} & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & -\frac{4}{5} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.\]

\end{document}
```

[image: A Crowded Matrix]

It's hard to read because the entries from other rows cover up some of the other entries a bit. I just want to know how to fix this. I apologize if this is a duplicate question. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question to add an image of your crowded matrix (and a missing `\end{document}`) See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) about using `\[` and `\]` instead of `$$` for displayed math.

Answer (score 2):

You should adjust `\arraystretch` which is a factor multiplying the row spacing.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  G_{10} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 &-\frac{2}{25} & -\frac{17}{100} & -\frac{13}{50} &
    -\frac{7}{20} & - \frac{11}{25} & -\frac{53}{100} & -\frac{31}{50}
    & -\frac{71}{100} & -
    \frac{4}{5} \\
    \frac{2}{25} & 0 & -\frac{1}{25} & -\frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{5} &
    - \frac{7}{25} & -\frac{9}{25} & -\frac{11}{25} & -\frac{13}{25} &
    -
    \frac{3}{5} \\
    \frac{17}{100} & \frac{1}{25} & 0 & \frac{1}{50} & -\frac{1}{20} &
    - \frac{3}{25} & -\frac{19}{100} & -\frac{13}{50} &
    -\frac{33}{100} & -
    \frac{2}{5} \\
    \frac{13}{50} & \frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{50} & 0 & \frac{1}{10} &
    \frac{1}{25} & -\frac{1}{50} & -\frac{2}{25} & -\frac{7}{50} & -
    \frac{1}{5} \\
    \frac{7}{20} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{20} & -\frac{1}{10} & 0 &
    \frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{20} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{20}  & 0 \\
    \frac{11}{25} & \frac{7}{25} & \frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{25} &
    -\frac{1}
    {5} & 0 & \frac{8}{25} & \frac{7}{25} & \frac{6}{25} & \frac{1}{5} \\
    \frac{53}{100} & \frac{9}{25} & \frac{19}{100} & \frac{1}{50} & -
    \frac{3}{20} & -\frac{8}{25} & 0 & \frac{23}{50} & \frac{43}{100}
    &
    \frac{2}{5} \\
    \frac{31}{50} & \frac{11}{25} & \frac{13}{50} & \frac{2}{25} & -
    \frac{1}{10} & -\frac{7}{25} & -\frac{23}{50} & 0 & \frac{31}{50}
    &
    \frac{3}{5} \\
    \frac{71}{100} & \frac{13}{25} & \frac{33}{100} & \frac{7}{50} & -
    \frac{1}{20} & -\frac{6}{25} & -\frac{43}{100} & -\frac{31}{50} &
    0 &
    \frac{4}{5} \\
    \frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 &
    -\frac{1}
    {5} & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & -\frac{4}{5} & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note I have put the redefinition of the `\arraystretch` inside the group defined by the equation, so it will not have effect outside that group.  If you wish to set this spacing for the whole document you should issue the `\renewcommand` either just after `\begin{document}`, or perhaps in the preamble.  The first option is safer, in the situation the value is change by other packages.

Please review your list of packages - several are already loaded by `amsart`.

Also you should not use `$$`, but one of the environments provided by `amsmath`.

Comment: Thank you. I've never written a Latex document before. My professor just told us to copy and paste the stuff at the top of the document he had and go from there. I didn't know what any of it did. He said to not worry about any of that and if we had any questions to ask him or go here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this is the `cellspace` package with option `[math]`. You can define a *minimal* padding at the top and bottom od matrix cells.

In addition, as there is a great contrast  in size between normal digits and fractions in matrices, I suggest to use the *medium-size* `\mfrac`  from `nccmath`. Below you can compare the result of both.

Unrelated: `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions. Also, needless to load `graohics` when you load `graphicx`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, latexsym, amsmath, amsthm, enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx, multicol, tikz, pgfplots, tkz-euclide, relsize, framed}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{fontscale/.style = {font=\relsize{#1}}}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.750in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumii}.}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}

\begin{document}

\[ G_{10} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-\frac{2}{25} & -\frac{17}{100} & -\frac{13}{50} & -\frac{7}{20} & -
\frac{11}{25} & -\frac{53}{100} & -\frac{31}{50} & -\frac{71}{100} & -
\frac{4}{5} \\
\frac{2}{25} & 0 & -\frac{1}{25} & -\frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{5} & -
\frac{7}{25} & -\frac{9}{25} & -\frac{11}{25} & -\frac{13}{25} & -
\frac{3}{5} \\
\frac{17}{100} & \frac{1}{25} & 0 & \frac{1}{50} & -\frac{1}{20} & -
\frac{3}{25} & -\frac{19}{100} & -\frac{13}{50} & -\frac{33}{100} & -
\frac{2}{5} \\
\frac{13}{50} & \frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{50} & 0 & \frac{1}{10} &
\frac{1}{25} & -\frac{1}{50} & -\frac{2}{25} & -\frac{7}{50} & -
\frac{1}{5} \\
\frac{7}{20} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{20} & -\frac{1}{10} & 0 &
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{20} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{20} & 0 \\
\frac{11}{25} & \frac{7}{25} & \frac{3}{25} & -\frac{1}{25} & -\frac{1}
{5} & 0 & \frac{8}{25} & \frac{7}{25} & \frac{6}{25} & \frac{1}{5} \\
\frac{53}{100} & \frac{9}{25} & \frac{19}{100} & \frac{1}{50} & -
\frac{3}{20} & -\frac{8}{25} & 0 & \frac{23}{50} & \frac{43}{100} &
\frac{2}{5} \\
\frac{31}{50} & \frac{11}{25} & \frac{13}{50} & \frac{2}{25} & -
\frac{1}{10} & -\frac{7}{25} & -\frac{23}{50} & 0 & \frac{31}{50} &
\frac{3}{5} \\
\frac{71}{100} & \frac{13}{25} & \frac{33}{100} & \frac{7}{50} & -
\frac{1}{20} & -\frac{6}{25} & -\frac{43}{100} & -\frac{31}{50} & 0 &
\frac{4}{5} \\
\frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & -\frac{1}
{5} & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & -\frac{4}{5} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.\]\bigskip

\[ G_{10} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-\mfrac{2}{25} & -\mfrac{17}{100} & -\mfrac{13}{50} & -\mfrac{7}{20} & -
\mfrac{11}{25} & -\mfrac{53}{100} & -\mfrac{31}{50} & -\mfrac{71}{100} & -
\mfrac{4}{5} \\
\mfrac{2}{25} & 0 & -\mfrac{1}{25} & -\mfrac{3}{25} & -\mfrac{1}{5} & -
\mfrac{7}{25} & -\mfrac{9}{25} & -\mfrac{11}{25} & -\mfrac{13}{25} & -
\mfrac{3}{5} \\
\mfrac{17}{100} & \mfrac{1}{25} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{50} & -\mfrac{1}{20} & -
\mfrac{3}{25} & -\mfrac{19}{100} & -\mfrac{13}{50} & -\mfrac{33}{100} & -
\mfrac{2}{5} \\
\mfrac{13}{50} & \mfrac{3}{25} & -\mfrac{1}{50} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{10} &
\mfrac{1}{25} & -\mfrac{1}{50} & -\mfrac{2}{25} & -\mfrac{7}{50} & -
\mfrac{1}{5} \\
\mfrac{7}{20} & \mfrac{1}{5} & \mfrac{1}{20} & -\mfrac{1}{10} & 0 &
\mfrac{1}{5} & \mfrac{3}{20} & \mfrac{1}{10} & \mfrac{1}{20} & 0 \\
\mfrac{11}{25} & \mfrac{7}{25} & \mfrac{3}{25} & -\mfrac{1}{25} & -\mfrac{1}
{5} & 0 & \mfrac{8}{25} & \mfrac{7}{25} & \mfrac{6}{25} & \mfrac{1}{5} \\
\mfrac{53}{100} & \mfrac{9}{25} & \mfrac{19}{100} & \mfrac{1}{50} & -
\mfrac{3}{20} & -\mfrac{8}{25} & 0 & \mfrac{23}{50} & \mfrac{43}{100} &
\mfrac{2}{5} \\
\mfrac{31}{50} & \mfrac{11}{25} & \mfrac{13}{50} & \mfrac{2}{25} & -
\mfrac{1}{10} & -\mfrac{7}{25} & -\mfrac{23}{50} & 0 & \mfrac{31}{50} &
\mfrac{3}{5} \\
\mfrac{71}{100} & \mfrac{13}{25} & \mfrac{33}{100} & \mfrac{7}{50} & -
\mfrac{1}{20} & -\mfrac{6}{25} & -\mfrac{43}{100} & -\mfrac{31}{50} & 0 &
\mfrac{4}{5} \\
\mfrac{4}{5} & \mfrac{3}{5} & \mfrac{2}{5} & \mfrac{1}{5} & 0 & -\mfrac{1}
{5} & -\mfrac{2}{5} & -\mfrac{3}{5} & -\mfrac{4}{5} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.\]

\end{document}
```

[image]